# PHP - Javascript Controls

Tags: php, javascript, controls

I'm currently developing (another) Open Source CMS in PHP and I'd like to use javascript controls especially for the admin panel. The question is, are there any open-source, freely distributable controls (for creating javascript Editable Grids, Trees, tabs etc ) that have an interface for PHP ?

I've experimented with [ExtJs](http://extjs.com/) in the past but although its usability and beauty when it comes to implementing it with php, it's a frustration. I've also tried PHP-EXT and ExtPHP libraries but I was disappointed by their generated code, their limited implementation of ExtJs and lack of proper documentation.

[Coolite](http://www.coolite.com/) is a nice implementation for .NET but I haven't found anything similar for php. That surprised me, taking into account the years of php development on the market.

Off course there's always the option of implementing different libraries for each component but this would become an overwhelming task, besides the incompatibilities and the difference in look&feel that are going to come up.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you creating yet another open source CMS when there's already excellent established solutions like Drupal and Joomla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) with their new [jQuery UI](http://ui.jquery.com/). Also, browse through their [plugins list](http://plugins.jquery.com/) for more tools.

But you might like [mootools](http://mootools.net/) too.

Answer (score 2):

Really the best thing to do is just to write the JavaScript interactions between your JS library and PHP yourself. Overall generated code wil never be fully changeable and most JS libraries take a mere day to learn how to use.

Best bet is to go with jQuery and jQuery UI as it has a lot of documentation and support.

Answer (score 0):

You might also like the [Yahoo! User Interface Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) which might be closer to Coolite.

Answer (score 0):

There is one framework I've seen for producing thick client web apps called [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/). Might be overkill for what you want to achive, but the demos just look so tasty.